# google maps api v3 not showing in IE8 but shows in chrome and FF and IE10

Tags: javascript, google-maps

SO Ive been working on this issue for a long time. Basically Im just adding the google maps onto my webpage. Im using the example from google maps API v3 website. It doesnt show in IE and i dont know why! It shows in chrome and FF and in IE 10 but not in IE8-9.

DOes anyone know why?

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&sensor=false">
</script>
   <div id='map' class="eventMap"></div>

function initialize()
{

var mapProp = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
  zoom:5,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapProp);


}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



    });
```

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages? The code sample above looks wrong, but guessing its a cut and paste issue..

Comment: how do you define the height for `#map`

Comment: I defined it in my CSS